# Haskell module loads but does not update any more. Only updates module name

Tags: haskell

So I am writing haskell functions. Everything was going good but for some reason, now my module is not getting updated, even though I intentionally cause errors. The only thing that seems to be updating is the module name or the actualy statement of defining the module. If for instance I remove the where clause it will error out, but even if I remove wors and mess up the syntax anywhere underneath, nothing happens. The imports are used for other parts of my program. Here is my code:

```
module HW32 where

import ImpSyntax

import ImpParser


data BinTree a =
    Empty
  | Node (BinTree a) a (BinTree a)
  deriving (Eq,Show)

prettyTree :: BinTree a -> String 
prettyTree Empty = ""
prettyTree (Node l x r) = "\n" + prettyTree l + " " + prettyTree r + " " + x "\n"
```

Comment: If the compiled bytecode file already exists, then the compiler doesn't always check the source code for changes (I think).  Make sure you're compiling with `-fforce-recomp`.

Comment: that our delete the byte code (.hi and .o files).

Comment: I do not see any .hi or .o files in my folder... Also, where would I use --fforce-recomp at ?

Comment: Are you using ghc to compile it or ghci to run it?